# Loading DataGridView only once based on listbox item selected

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a WinForm App using Visual Studio 2017.
I created a list box as follows.
[image]

the following dataGridview would appear when i click Fruits for the first time.

[image]

i.e whenever i press fruits i should get the above data grid. and similarly corresponding values for vegetables too. But the problem is when i click fruits one more time again the values are getting added. I get the same values again instead of just retaining it. Here is my code.

```
public Form1()
    {          
        FruitList.Add("Mango");
        FruitList.Add("Apple");

        InitializeComponent();
    }
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (a == "Fruits")
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = a;
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("key", "Fruit");
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("value", "Name");
            foreach (var var in FruitList)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add("Fruit", var);
            }

        }
    }
```

And when i select Vegetable only values related to that should appear in dataGridview. But I am getting all things addedd up as i click the item in listbox

How to load the dataGridView values only once.
I am completely new to visual studio and C#. Just exploring various features of it. It would be nice if anyone could help. Thanks in advance

As per er-shoaib 's answer after adding,

```
 dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
```

On above the line

```
string a = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

I get the contents reloaded.

This is fine unless i dont delete or make any changes. If i delete a selected row say the row Mango using a Button control and when i press the Fruits item in List again , the items are loaded from the beginning. How to make the changes retain throughout the app. Like till i close the Form. Any help on this.

Comment: add this line `dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();` above that line `string a = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();` and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear all the rows before filling new rows to data grid view when you click on item in list box.

Add this line

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
```

On above the line

```
string a = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: This is fine unless i dont delete or make any changes. If i delete a selected row say the row Mango using a Button control and when i press the Fruits item in List again , the items are loaded from the beginning. How to make the changes retain throughout the app. Like till i close the Form.

Comment: means if you delete Mango then it can be deleted from FruitList also so next time you will get only Apple when you select Fruit in ListBox?

Comment: yeah that is possible. by deleting the list value , i can do that. But is that possible by using any of the dataGridView or WINForm feature or any other hack?

Comment: You have to implement logic for your need and develop a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Before for loop, clear the datagrid and then start for loop and add items.

```
    datagrid2.rows.clear().
```